# Vectorised Timezone Identifier

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pytz

I'm trying to create a vectorised implementation of the following function, as currently using pandas apply with my dataframe takes too long, but coming unstuck. Can anyone help?

```
    """
    Returns GMT if date is between clock changes in winter, and BST if date is between clock changes in summer
    """
    import pytz
    timezone_str = 'Europe/London'
    timezone = pytz.timezone(timezone_str)
    t = timezone.utcoffset(d)
    timezone = 'GMT' if t.seconds==0 else 'BST'
    return timezone
```

Comment: why not check the utcoffset in pandas, i.e. on an aware datetime Series?

Comment: just seen this, stuck using an env with an old pandas version / various dependancies and need a quick fix.

Comment: what means old pandas version? If you have a datetime Series with tz set to "Europe/London", what you need could be as simple as `df["datetime"].dt.strftime("%Z")`.

Comment: Thanks @FObersteiner! Seems obvious although I never deal with timezones so wasn't aware of tz_localise pr %Z in datetime object. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an illustration of my comment; are you looking for [strftime's "%Z"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)?

```py
import pandas as pd

# a dummy example
df = pd.DataFrame({"dt": ["2022-01-05", "2022-08-05"]})
# assuming we have aware datetime
df["dt"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dt"]).dt.tz_localize("Europe/London")

df["zone"] = df["dt"].dt.strftime("%Z")

print(df)
                         dt zone
0 2022-01-05 00:00:00+00:00  GMT
1 2022-08-05 00:00:00+01:00  BST
```